# Dropbox file downloading is not working when iOS application is goes to Background or screen locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api, core-api

I hopefully integrated **DropboxSDK [CORE API]** in to my application. I can able to do view my contents through my Application and I can able to download. But my Problem is, When I press the Home button or locked my iDevice download is canceled.

And it showing ERROR like this.

> "[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files/dropbox/Shadow 30s_mpeg4.mp4 - (1002) Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=1002 The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 1002.)" UserInfo=0x1681f2b0 {path=/Shadow 30s_mpeg4.mp4, destinationPath=/var/mobile/Applications/728071A1-1BB9-481D-A3FE-07C791397568/Documents/Shadow 30s_mpeg4.mp4}..

Please. Can anyone help me out of this Problem. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier  taskId = 0;
    taskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        taskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}
```

just add this code to AppDelegate.m and it will give about 10 min after app enter background